# Why can I pass a value to the printf C function like this?

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I was searching pointers in C and on a given website I found the following usage:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    int array[5] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i[array]); /* Instead of "array[i]"" */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How does it happen and why does `printf` function understand this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C `a[b]` will essentially became `*(a + b)` so if you would do `b[a]` you would get `*(b + a)` which is the same. That is why this code works.